# Mongodb sum duplicates count

Tags: mongodb, count, sum, aggregate

Having a collection of records counted by user (user1 has 4 records, user2, has 10 records)
i'd like sum users with the same quantity of records for obtains this result in mongodb

users with 5 records: 100
users with 10 records: 120
.
.
.

Comment: what have you tried? can you provide your schema? you need to provide a minimal reproducible example of the issue. this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$count",
      "users": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7J_cLJG3qe1)

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for,